# Display entry title inside an images

Tags: templates, metadata

I'm sure this is a basic question (EE is not my bag): I am trying to create a fallback for an image's alt text where if the image does not have a description then to use the title of the entry in its place.

But obviously if I use

```
{image}
  <img src="{url}" alt="{if description}{description}{if:else}{title}{/if}"> 
{/image}
```

Then it uses the image's title.

How do I make it display the entry title instead?

TIA.

Comment: What kind of field is this?

Answer (score 0):

Can you give me a little more information about your code here?

`{image}` is a grid field? What fields does the grid have? Perhaps you could rename the `{title}` field in your grid to something that doesn't overwrite the default `{title}` field?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the file fieldtype..if so with the variable pair tag.. i guess you can't get the entry title!??.. But if you have only 1 image.. you may try something like..

`{image limit="1"}
  <img src="{url}" alt="{if description}{description}"{/image}{if:else}{/image}{title}"{/if}>`

It's not elegant.. and i didn't test it.. !